# White vs Brown adipose tissue

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have been looking for a reference that compares and contrasts brown and white adipose tissue (in humans) in a concise (preferably tabular, but that's not completely necessary) manner. I haven't found one yet. So I was thinking of posting a question asking for such a reference, along with my own simple table that I've been compiling along the way, in case anyone thought of commenting on it /critiquing it /adding to it . Is that an acceptable question ?

Answer (score 4):

Would "What are the differences between white and brown adipose tissue?" not be acceptable? This seems imminently answerable, and a table would suffice.

Comment: Sounds like a plan ! Thanks, I'll prepare the question now...

Answer (score 3):

That sounds useful, but I don't really think this fits into the Q+A format SE is going for: not only is it asking for a list with no clear "right" answer, if people post replies it has the potential to become a list of lists. I'm curious to know what you've been compiling it from: if your sources are well cited it seems like a perfect addition to Wikipedia.

As for the asking where you'd find such a reference: I'm not sure what the biology.SE stance is on asking for references (comments welcome).

Comment: Thanks. On other SE sites, I would think this falls in the category of "community wiki" which exists on on stats.SE where I have also posted a little - for example see [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/290/what-is-community-wiki) - could I not just use the same tag on biology.se ?

Comment: It seems like you have two posts here: one is the question "where do I find this list?", the other is a community wiki in which the answers are the differences. You could cross link them, but I don't think they belong together. We don't seem to have a precedent on either of these uses, so I'd say go for it, see what people say.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ideal as a community wiki, no ?